# How to indent paragraphs within a block quote?

Tags: xetex, indentation, overleaf, chicago-style, parindent

I have to do a block quotation that spans across one paragraph into the next. The 17th edition of the Chicago manual of style seems to advise (in 13.22) that indents should be used for new paragraphs within the block quotation.

However, whenever I try to make a second paragraph on a new line start with an indent, my LaTeX editor (Overleaf) refuses to add the indent. I've tried the following four approaches and none of them seems to work:

```
\begin{quote}
This is the first paragraph.
\newline\indent I want this to have an indent.
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}
This is the first paragraph.
\newline\tab I want this to have an indent.
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}
This is the first paragraph.
\newline\hspace{\parindent} I want this to have an indent.
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}
This is the first paragraph.
\newline ~~~~I want this to have an indent.
\end{quote}
```

How do I achieve my objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `quotation` environment, instead of `quote`, and separate paragraphs within the environment with a blank line. There is no need to manually add indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Text before quotation.

\begin{quotation}
  This is the first paragraph.
  This is the first paragraph.
  This is the first paragraph.

  This is the second paragraph.
  This is the second paragraph.
  This is the second paragraph.
\end{quotation}

Text after quotation.
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Here is my attempt to modify the quotation environment from the article class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quotation}
               {\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
                        \rightmargin   \leftmargin
                        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text before quotation.

\begin{quotation}
  This is the first paragraph.
  This is the first paragraph.
  This is the first paragraph.

  This is the second paragraph.
  This is the second paragraph.
  This is the second paragraph.
\end{quotation}

Text after quotation.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works. The downside is that the first paragraph now starts with an indent, but I was able to fix that by prefixing it with a \noindent. I want to implement block quotations in accordance with CMOS guidelines, so I'd have to write \noindent for the first paragraph every time and wonder if there's a way to avoid having to do that each time?

Comment: @AWriterWhoAsks I've edited my answer to modify the quotation environment to not indent the first paragraph. I'm a little out of my league with this sort of modification, so _caveat emptor_, but it seems to work.